# LOTR CG: May I keep the resource tokens of a dying hero?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

Do I discard the resource tokens of a hero that dies or may I keep them? I assume I need to discard them. But I didn't find this info in the rulebook.

The resouce token belong to a certain sphere of influence, yes, but if I have another hero of the same sphere left, then theoretically I could move the resource token of the dying hero to the other hero.

Answer (score 2):

Tokens on a card are discarded when the hero dies, the comprehensive rules cover this under *Leaving Play*

> **Leaving Play**: When a card (other than a site) leaves play for any reason, any cards played on that card (or borne by or stacked on that
> card) are discarded. Any tokens on that card are removed.